# How do I clear any output files for Lazarus (or perhaps Delphi)?

Tags: debugging, lazarus

I was stumped when my recent Lazarus Pascal project started giving out a strange CIRCULAR REFERENCE error 2 days ago.

I have now removed ALL elements of the project and only have the LPR file open. When I hit F9 to compile and run, I see the same error. So I suspect that there are some older output files that are messing up.

How can I identify and delete them so that my project will compile?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Lazarus 1.0.10 + PostgreSQL

Thanks a million!

EDIT: 2013-11-02

I've just come back from a TSUNAMI! I tried a lot of things and finally formatted my OS and came back afresh. New projects work fine. But my old project with the problem is still the same. It fires a circular reference error:

```
stdctrls.pp(9,52) Fatal: Circular unit reference between StdCtrls and LCLIntf
```

The funny thing is that the said line is BLANK. There are comments before and after it. My concern is WHY? I am NOT using LCLIntf anywhere in my code.

EDIT: 2013-11-03

I noticed a strange thing. I had an LPS file for the project. It had some entries with references to StdCtrls. I then changed the project option to NOT use session file. Instead it uses LPI file only. But now I find the same StdCtrls entry in my LPI file. I don't know why this is happening. I opened the LPI file's entry referring to StdCtrls (and even removed the backup file). But everytime I open it in Lazarus, the entry is back in there.

This is the entry I found and deleted.

```
  <Unit29>
    <Filename Value="/usr/share/lazarus/1.0.12/lcl/stdctrls.pp"/>
    <UnitName Value="StdCtrls"/>
    <WindowIndex Value="0"/>
    <TopLine Value="1"/>
    <CursorPos X="52" Y="9"/>
    <UsageCount Value="10"/>
  </Unit29>
```

I strongly believe that this is the one that is causing the circular reference error.

Any idea on HOW I can get rid of this and fix my project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are other possible causes. Mutual references can cause seeming fleeting behaviour (depending on compilation order). Cross-unit inlining aggrevates it.

Try to minimize it to a few unit, and then play with mutual references (units using eachother, either directly or as part of an USES cycle), and disable all inlining in the relevant units first.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't remove any unit. I only have one for each form and two additional units that have common functions. That's all. But I think it's some internal call between LCLIntf and StdCtrls that's causing the disaster. Thanks anyway for your input. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Do you know when and why LCLIntf gets called by a standard form, and in addition to the lfm and pas files where would I look for code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Shift-F9 - it will run *build*, which should compile all files from scratch. If this still will not help, you can try to remove some `.ppu` files which are compiled units. However, be careful to do not remove Lazarus' own `.ppu`, which are needed for compilation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. I tried your methods but they don't seem to work either:/